# VK_API: Problems with music, json decoder

Tags: python, vk

I'm trying to make a special parser for VK, which downloads all music from page of some user, but there's some problem with vk_api, which allows to access audiofiles. I'm trying to call method get() to get list of all tracks, but launch of this program:

```
session = vk_api.VkApi(token=tkn)
vk = session.get_api()
vk_audio = audio.VkAudio(session)


def get_list_audio():
    dct = vk_audio.get(owner_id=owner_id, album_id=None, access_hash=None)
    return dct

print(get_list_audio())
```

shows nothing but an error, connected with json decoder:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ann\PycharmProjects\vk-parser\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(get_list_audio())
  File "C:\Users\ann\PycharmProjects\vk-parser\main.py", line 38, in get_list_audio
    dct = vk_audio.get(owner_id=owner_id, album_id=None, access_hash=None)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\vk-parser\lib\site-packages\vk_api\audio.py", line 158, in get
    return list(self.get_iter(owner_id, album_id, access_hash))
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\vk-parser\lib\site-packages\vk_api\audio.py", line 107, in get_iter
    response = self._vk.http.post(
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\vk-parser\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Please, give some hints, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

vk_api/audio.py makes just POST request to m.vk.com/audio:

[image]

and the error occures when it tries to convert the response to json (line 119). If we run these lines manually (or you can use debugger anytime to see what happens), we see 302 http error with empty response. json() can't get json from this empty response, so you see the exception. You have to choose another library (to work with vk api) or to write these actions yourself. Or to fix this lib code :)

Probably, this vk_api library does not support the changes that have occurred in vk.com. You can take this code from the library and make your own method for getting audio based on it.